# Image Processing Suite for bacterial microscopy: Schnitzcells or MicrobeTracker?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, bacteriology, microscopy

I am looking to start doing some work tracking the size and growth of individual bacterial cells in the microscope. In order to analyze the images I need software that can segment the cells, accurately determine their shape, and track cell lineages on a 'movie' of images collected from one experiment. Given the constraints of my microscope setup, the easiest thing for me to do is to use a strain of bacteria constitutively expressing GFP and segment the cells based on fluorescent intensity. This is functionally equivalent to segmented phase-contrast images of wild-type cells, i.e. I'm not that interested in changes in fluorescence or using fluorescence as a gene expression reporter, though my needs may head in that direction.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel (and I think that it's better if the community consolidates around a few programs that everyone uses so that experiments can be more comparable), so I'm looking for a previously published package that is robust and easy to use. Flexibility at measuring fluorescent tracking is nice, but at this stage is not crucial. The two packages that I have seen are [Schnitzcells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22179594) from the Elowitz lab at CalTech and [Microbetracker](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21414037) from the Emonet and Jacobs-Wagner groups at Yale. Unfortunately they were released at the same time and don't provide a good comparison of the pros/cons of each tool.

Finally, my question is

> What are your recommendations for an image analysis suite (from the two packages above or another package you have used)?

Let me know if I can make my criteria more clear or anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Although I haven't done live image tracking and analysis myself but I know the main method that people use is through Matlab, which means programming/coding so you would have to find someone to help you with some coding if you haven't worked with it before. Otherwise I suggest looking at fiji Image-J since it has a wide variety of open source plug-ins. I personally use image-J very very frequently and I'm very happy with it.